# Libreoffice: Import columns of spreadsheet as fields

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-writer, mail-merge

I have a LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet with Columns A, B, C.

I would like to create a document in LibreOffice Writer with format:
A1
B1
C1

A2
B2
C2...

Comment: I ended up using Microsoft Word's Mail Merge Wizard with document type Directory. I am still curious if this is possible via LibreOffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can:

1. Save your **LibreOffice Calc spreadsheet** (preferably with proper header-names and sheet-names)
2. Make a new **LibreOffice Base database** with type Spreadsheet.  (I find 'publishing' it, easier in usage.)
   It will interpret the sheets as tables and the columns as columns (duh).  Optionally make appropriate queries, to manipulate or filter your data.
   (Note that [David Burke](http://davidmburke.com/2011/08/10/mail-merge-in-libreoffice/) seems to do it without using Base.)
3. In your **LibreOffice Writer-document**

   1. select your **database**, by menu View | Data Sources
      (Next time Writer will remember the right data source, but it will not reopen this view automatically.)
   2. In the Data Sources window select the **sheet** in Tables (or your query in Queries)
   3. The data will be shown. Drag the column-header for the **field**(s) you want into your document.  (Dropping in the right place may be hard. However, once dropped, you can cut and paste it to the right place.)
   4. To preview the **contents** of the fields, select the right record by clicking on the row 'header' (the whole row should be highlighted).
      Then click on the icon for "data to fields" above the data (the icon shows text with two blue arrows around a field)
   5. To '**print** all data' (in the dialog you can also choose to save to file, and to filter your data-rows) use the Print-command (e.g. from the file-menu) agreeing to use mail merge in the (first) dialog-window.
      Notice that printing through the Mail Merge Wizard (using the Tools-menu or the envelops-icon), has (had?) some bugs (e.g. [filtering](https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=52586#c3)).
      (To Print the previewed content-fields example item (as test), use the Print menu denying to use mail merge.)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using LibreOffice Base (the db component). Just create a new database with type `Spreadsheet`. It will handle the sheet's rows as datasets and the first row as field names. Now, you can generate a report that lists the column names (field names) and the values of every row.